# External storage not detected on macbook air 2015

Tags: usb, storage

So I have a MacBook Air late 2015 that I recently got from a friend, but neither of the usb ports work for usb storage nor does the sd card slot work. However whatever I connect does show up in the system information. Just not in the Disk Utilities nor in the finder. I've already reset the SMC and reinstalled the OS. I honestly don't know what to do now.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). Also, have you tried [resetting the NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/HT204063) to see if that helps?

Comment: @Monomeeth holy shingles thank you!! I thought I'd done so already after seeing someone else post to do so but apparently I did it wrong since they said to wait for the screen to flash!! It's working great now :D